# How to update two columns in a table with an aggregate function in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I've tried several options but I can't find the right solution.
I want to update two columns in the `Products` table.
These columns need to be updated from another table called `ProductShops`.

The two columns are named `LowestPrice` and `LowestPriceShopId`.
So I need the lowest value from the sum `NewPrice + DeliveryCosts` in `ProductShops` and the `ShopId` from that record.
That needs to be updated in the `Products` table.

Things that I've tried are:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET LowestPrice = MIN(ps.NewPrice + ps.DeliveryCosts), 
LowestPriceShopId = ps.ShopId 
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN ProductShops ps ON Products.Id = ps.ProductId
```

Error message : An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE p 
SET LowestPrice = ps2.totalPrice,
LowestPriceShopId = ps2.ShopId
FROM Products p JOIN
(select ps.ProductId, MIN(ps.NewPrice + ps.DeliveryCosts) AS totalPrice, ShopId FROM ProductShops ps) ps2
ON p.Id = ps2.ProductId
```

Error message: Column 'ProductShops.ProductId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
UPDATE Products
SET LowestPrice = (SELECT MIN(ps.NewPrice + ps.DeliveryCosts) 
FROM ProductShops ps WHERE ps.ProductId = p.Id)
FROM Products p
```

With the last query I don't know how to get the `ShopId`.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE p
SET LowestPrice = ps2.totalPrice,
    LowestPriceShopId = ps2.ShopId
FROM Products p
JOIN (SELECT
    ps.ProductId,
    MIN(ps.NewPrice + ps.DeliveryCosts) AS totalPrice,
    ShopId
FROM ProductShops ps
GROUP BY ps.ProductId,ShopId) ps2
    ON p.Id = ps2.ProductId
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the right solution:

```
UPDATE p 
SET LowestPrice = ps3.totalPrice,
LowestPriceShopId = ps3.ShopId
FROM Products p 
JOIN
(
SELECT ps1.ProductId, ps1.NewPrice + ps1.DeliveryCosts as totalPrice, ps1.ShopId FROM ProductShops ps1 
LEFT JOIN ProductShops ps2
ON ps1.ProductId = ps2.ProductId AND (ps1.NewPrice + ps1.DeliveryCosts) > (ps2.NewPrice + ps2.DeliveryCosts)
WHERE ps2.NewPrice is NULL AND ps2.DeliveryCosts is NULL
) ps3
ON p.Id = ps3.ProductId
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY`:

```
UPDATE p 
SET LowestPrice = ps2.totalPrice,
LowestPriceShopId = ps2.ShopId
FROM Products p 
JOIN
(
    select 
        ps.ProductId, 
        MIN(ps.NewPrice)+MIN(ps.DeliveryCosts) AS totalPrice, 
        ShopId 
    FROM 
        ProductShops ps
    GROUP BY
        ps.ProductId,
        ps.ShopId
) ps2
ON p.Id = ps2.ProductId
```

On both `ProductId` and `ShopId`

Comment: I have 2 ProductShops records with the same ProductId, but if i run the query the higest price is added to the Product record. Do you know how this can happen?

Comment: @Pim : I updated the answer. It might be that the total of `ps.NewPrice + ps.DeliveryCosts` is higher then `NewPrice` and `DeliveryCosts` individual. So test the query like this